# Failed to download metadata for repo appstream

Tags: centos, centos8

Running on `centos 8` today want to install new package and before it wants to run:

`yum update -y`

but got this:

> Failed to download metadata for repo 'appstream': Cannot prepare
> internal mirrorlist: No URLs in mirrorlist

Then I did search and found a [solution](https://yegorshytikov.medium.com/error-failed-to-download-metadata-for-repo-appstream-cannot-prepare-internal-mirrorlist-no-959768e5f8e5) to fix it:

```
sed -i 's/mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
sed -i 's|#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org|baseurl=http://vault.centos.org|g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
```

I did this but still error persist, any idea? how to fix this? Is there new solution in 2022?

After use this [solution](https://haydenjames.io/fix-error-failed-to-download-metadata-for-repo-appstream-centos-8/)

Now error:

> Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'extras':
>
> - Status code: 403 for https://vault.centos.org/centos/8/extras/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml
>   (IP: 13.249.9.66) Error: Failed to download metadata for repo
>   'extras': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download
>   repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried

Comment: https://haydenjames.io/fix-error-failed-to-download-metadata-for-repo-appstream-centos-8/

Comment: @GoinOff still return error, updated on question

Comment: Since you can't update CentOS 8 any longer using yum, you must move to CentOS 8 Stream or go to Red Hat instead.  The relevant potion of the link I sent should be followed:

Comment: To migrate from CentOS 8 to CentOS Stream 8, run the following commands:

`dnf --disablerepo '*' --enablerepo=extras swap centos-linux-repos centos-stream-repos`
`dnf distro-sync`

Comment: Did u find solution yet